# ViewHolder and changing one row details

Tags: android, android-listview

I'm using a listview with a special layout as row like this

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/backColor"
    android:id="@+id/linearLayoutMain"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtName"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:textColor="@color/RedColor"
            android:text="M"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtFamily"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/txtName"
            android:layout_below="@+id/txtName"
            android:paddingBottom="5dp"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
            android:text="S"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />
</LinearLayout>
```

and I'm using ViewHolder as usual.
When user Tap on **linearLayoutMain** the text of **txtName** will Change; but How Can I save the new value of **txtName** even during scroll?

Actually I don't want to change dataset; I'm going to do something like this
I used to set **currentContact.Name** as text for **txtName**
Now want to do something like this :

```
txtName.settext(currentContact.Nickname);
```

Comment: onclick event of linear layout you can perform operations like saving data in database & setting changed text to textview.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> but How Can I save the new value of txtName even during scroll?

you have to modify to element in the dataset you used to fill up the `ListView`

Comment: Hi; Imagine I have two difference field for Name and Nickname and I will switch from Name to Nickname when user tap; Is there any way not to change value of dataset? for example **txtName.settext(mylst.Nickname)** instead of changing Name to Nickname